# Get all Woocommerce product IDs in an array

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How do I get IDs of all products in one array?

The output should be a simple array containing some numbers, nothing more.

I have been advised against using `query_posts()`, so I would prefer a solution not using this function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is multiple ways to get all product ids in an array:

1) Using Woocommerce [`WC_Product_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query):

```
$ids = wc_get_products( array( 'return' => 'ids', 'limit' => -1 ) );
```

2) Using Wordpress [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) *(including product variations IDs)*,

```
$ids = get_posts( array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_type' => array('product','product_variation'),
  'fields' => 'ids',
) );
```

3) Using a [`WPDB`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) *(a SQL query)* *(including product variation IDS)*:

```
global $wpdb;
$ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type IN ('product','product_variation')");
```

> In the 2 last ways you can remove `'product_variation'` post type, if you don't want it.